# CSRF token not working (access denied)

Tags: 8, csrf

I can get CSRF token to be generated on particular route by putting _crsf_token in a routing file, but on visiting that route , I keep getting an *Access Denied* error.

Removing CSRF token line from the routing file gives me back access to the access instantly.

What could be possibly wrong?

I have tried to make sense of [Menu Callback and CSRF](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/175697/menu-callback-and-csrf) but don't think it is related to my problem.

Comment: You should show your route definition, or users cannot point out to any mistakes in your route definition.

Comment: Also the code where you generate the link/path for the route. https://www.drupal.org/node/2575519 was fixed less than 24h ago and could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

@Berdir
Applying patch #14 on this page has solved the problem!
Thank you very much!

[Twig template variables containing result of Drupal::url() and Drupal:l:() don't bubble up their cacheability and attachment metadata (e.g. token placeholder)](https://www.drupal.org/node/2575519#comment-11160079)